# Image hovering using html or css

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I was trying to change an image on my page when i hover over it. I have also seen many examples about this and i'm still unable to make this work. Can anyone please tell me where am i going wrong?

Here is html my code:-

```
  <body>
        <a id="swap"> </a>
    </body>
```

css:-

```
 #swap {
        background-image:url('slide1.jpg');
    }

#swap:hover {
    background-image:url('slide2.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#swap {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url(slide1.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

#swap:hover {
    background-image: url(slide2.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
} 
</style>

<body>

     <a href=""><div id="swap"></div></a>

</body>
```

Change `width` and `height` to your image dimentions. This solution works, I tested.

Comment: so the width and height and of the image should be less than the width and height of the id "swap" right?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
#swap {
   display: block;
   background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-100-100-8.jpg') no-repeat; 
}
#swap:hover {
   background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/catsq-c-100-100-9.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```